# LWC navigate to the record detail page after creation

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, navigation, navigationmixin.navigate

I want to navigate to the record detail page after it has been created using the lightning web component.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Create Tender Tracker Support Case" icon-name="standard:case_wrap_up" class="headerTitle">
        <template if:true={showLoading}>
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium" class="spinnerClass"></lightning-spinner>
        </template>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">

                <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label"><span class="required-star">* </span>Subject</legend> 
                <lightning-input variant="label-hidden" value='' data-field="Subject" class="slds-m-bottom_x-small" required></lightning-input>

                <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">Case Summary</legend> 
                <lightning-textarea variant="label-hidden" value='' data-field="CaseSummary" class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-textarea>            

                <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">Opportunity Name</legend>
                <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Tender_Tracker_Case__c" > 
                <lightning-input-field field-name='Opportunity__c' name="Opportunity" data-field="Opportunity" class="slds-m-bottom_x-small" variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleLookupFieldChange}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                </lightning-record-edit-form>
                <br>
                
                <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">Urgent</legend> 
                <lightning-combobox name="Urgent" data-field="Urgent" variant="label-hidden" value={urgentValue} onchange={handleChange} placeholder="No" options={options}  >
                </lightning-combobox>
                <br>

                <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">Confidential</legend> 
                <lightning-combobox name="Confidential" data-field="Confidential" variant="label-hidden" value={confidentialValue} onchange={handleChange} placeholder="No" options={options} >
                </lightning-combobox>
                <br>

                <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">Must Win</legend> 
                <lightning-combobox name="MustWin" data-field="MustWin" variant="label-hidden" value={mustWinValue} onchange={handleChange} placeholder="No" options={options} >
                </lightning-combobox>
                <br>

                <!-- Buttons -->
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Cancel" class="cancelButton" type="reset" onclick={handleCancel}>
                </lightning-button>

                <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleCreate} variant="brand" class="saveButton">
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord, getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';

const fields = [NAME_FIELD];

export default class CreateRecordLWC extends LightningElement {
    @track showLoading = false;
    @api recordId;

    urgentValue = 'No';
    confidentialValue = 'No';
    mustWinValue = 'No';
    lookupId;

    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$lookupId',
        fields
    })
    opportunity;
    get opportunityName() {
        return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, NAME_FIELD);
    }
    handleLookupFieldChange(event) {
        this.lookupId = event.target.value;
    }

    // used for picklist fields
    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'No', value: 'No' },
            { label: 'Yes', value: 'Yes' },
        ];
    }

    handleCancel(){
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(element => {
            element.value = null;
        });
    }

    handleCreate() {
        const allValid = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
            .reduce((validSoFar, inputFields) => {
                inputFields.reportValidity();
                return validSoFar && inputFields.checkValidity();
            }, true);

        if (allValid) {
            this.showLoading = true;
            // Create the recordInput object
            var fields = { 'Subject__c': this.template.querySelector("[data-field='Subject']").value, 
                           'TT_Case_Summary__c': this.template.querySelector("[data-field='CaseSummary']").value,
                           'Opportunity__c': this.template.querySelector("[data-field='Opportunity']").value,
                           'Urgent__c': this.template.querySelector("[data-field='Urgent']").value,
                           'TT_Confidential__c': this.template.querySelector("[data-field='Confidential']").value,
                           'TT_Must_Win__c': this.template.querySelector("[data-field='MustWin']").value,
                        };

            const recordInput = { 'apiName': 'Tender_Tracker_Case__c', fields };
            console.log(recordInput);

            createRecord(recordInput)
                .then((record) => {
                    this.showToast('Success!!', 'Case created successfully!! ' + record.id, 'success', 'dismissable');
                    this.showLoading = false;
                    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                        type: 'standard__recordPage',
                        attributes: {
                            recordId: record.id,
                            objectApiName: 'Tender_Tracker_Case__c',
                            actionName: 'view'
                        },
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.showLoading = false;
                    console.log(error);
                    this.showToast('Error!!', error.body.message, 'error', 'dismissable');
                }); 
        }
        else {
            // The form is not valid
            this.showToast('Error!!', 'Check your input and try again.', 'error', 'dismissable');
        }

    }

    showToast(title, message, variant, mode) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant,
            mode: mode
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

The above code creates the record but does not navigate to the record details page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling the result of your `createRecord` correctly. In your `then`, you need a parameter for the record. Then you can get the Id from that. Currently, you're using `event.detail.id` but there is no `event`.

You need to do:

```
createRecord(recordInput)
    .then((record) => {
        this.showToast('Success!!', 'Case created successfully!!', 'success', 'dismissable');
        // Display fresh data in the form
        this.showLoading = false;
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: record.id,
                objectApiName: 'Tender_Tracker_Case__c',
                actionName: 'view'
            }})
    })
```

In the above code, we have used `record` for the result of the `createRecord` method. Then we can reference it within the `then` method.

Comment: Hi. I updated the question and added the complete HTML and JS files. The changes that you suggested is not working for me.

Comment: You need to replace `() =>` with `(record) =>`

Comment: I updated the JS file based on your suggestions. I can successfully get the record Id on the showToast message but it still does not navigate to the record page. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What happens if you put a `try-catch` around the `Navigate` bit? Maybe that'll tell you an error message

Comment: I changes "export default class CreateRecordLWC extends LightningElement" to "export default class CreateRecordLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)" and it worked. Thank you for your suggestions.